# React navigation back screen why removed header and bottom tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

You can find more details below. index.js app.js package.json nothing more  index.js app.js package.json nothing more react navigation rollback not working. Stays on the same page and removes header and bottom. and then it freezes i can't click anything

```js
 /**
     * @format
     */
    import React from 'react';
    import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
    import App from './App';
    import {name as appName} from './app.json';
    import 'react-native-gesture-handler'

       
    AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

    import * as React from 'react';
    import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

    function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Home Screen</Text>
          <Button
            title="Go to Details"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }

    function DetailsScreen() {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Details Screen</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }

    const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

    function App() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }

    export default App;



    //package.json
    {
      "name": "smartiq",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest",
        "lint": "eslint ."
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
        "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2",
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
        "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^7.0.0",
        "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.2.0",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
        "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
        "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.0.6",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
        "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.2",
        "axios": "^0.24.0",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-native": "0.66.3",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
        "react-native-modalize": "^2.0.12",
        "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.9",
        "react-native-paper": "^4.10.0",
        "react-native-portalize": "^1.0.7",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^2.3.0-beta.3",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
        "react-native-screens": "^3.9.0",
        "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
        "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
        "react-native-ui-lib": "^6.3.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
        "redux": "^4.1.2",
        "styled-components": "^5.3.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
        "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
        "eslint": "7.14.0",
        "jest": "^26.6.3",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
        "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
      },
      "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
      }
    }
```

I switch between pages in the application, when I click the back button, only the content comes up, the bottom tab and the top header are missing.
[Please check gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYqPE.gif)

Comment: Please post your code instead of the gif.

Comment: This same example code expo snack https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating

Comment: ok, that is the example code and how you have implemented it in your editor, post that code.

Comment: Think you've opened a new clean project, install everything from scratch. It looks like indexjs is installed, I wrote the code in app.js. I used the code exactly in the same project, but I thought I was making a mistake somewhere, so I tested it in app.js, but it's the same there. exactly the same as the document code

Comment: your code function DetailsScreen({ navigation }) is missing.

Comment: but I don't use navigation on details screen, why do we need it?

Comment: don't want to navigate back to the home screen?

Comment: I think there is no problem in the code because I get all the codes from the react navigaiton site, I try them in their simplest form in my project, it doesn't work. Is there a problem with the packages?

Comment: I did as you said but it didn't work.

Comment: what do you want actually? To navigate between to screen using react native?

Comment: For example didn't work back https://snack.expo.dev/@mitrabilisim/getting-started-%7C-react-navigation

Comment: I want to close the screen where I click on the top left back button of react navigation and go back to the previous screen

Comment: its returning back to previous screen when you click back button.

Comment: yes, it works in the snack I throw, but I put the same code in my project and it doesn't work. Why

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a component which contain the top and bottom content in your code

And you need to invoke the  component.

Comment: Hello, I'm already adding. I thought I'm making a mistake somewhere, I tested the code in app.js, it's exactly the same as the code in the documentation, but I got the same result.